# Unable to run a program in Visual studio 2019, Selecting Local Windows Debugger gives me error Access denied

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, cmake-gui

Currently, I am working on cloning the Cilantro github repository. I did using Cmake and also downloaded the required dependencies. The issue is I cannot run any files inside the project as well as newly created .cpp files for testing.
When I build the project it does builds successfully. but Whenever, I try to run by clicking in  Local windows debugger I keep getting error unable to start program access denied.

[snapshot of my current error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsyrS.png)

Things, I have done but not helped

1. uninstall MC*** antivirus
2. disabled the Real-time protection in systems virus security
3. rebuild the project and it build successfully

[snapshot successfull Rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MlhK.png)

4. also tried making cilantro as my set as project but than I am getting following error.
   [cilantro, set as project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMDXf.png)
   I need help to run the project and remove the following error. Also,is there an easier way to clone and run the project in visual studios without using CMAKE GUI?

IDE: Visual Studios; Trying to run C++ program
Used CMAKE gui to build this project Cilantro
Github which I am trying to run is : https://github.com/kzampog/cilantro

Comment: Maybe you need to set a target as a startup project:
On solution explorer, switch to CMake target view and right click, then "Set as Startup Project".

Comment: There is no application to launch from the `ALL_BUILD` project. Launch one of the examples. (You probably want to find yourself an introduction to Visual Studio.)

Comment: Even though i do that it keeps showing me an error unable to start the application, not a valid win32 application

Answer (score 0):

make you project as `set as startup project`

`Solution Explorer` > **`cilantro`** (Right click) > `set as startup project`

official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I still get the error but it different one now unable to start program not a valid win32 application

Comment: add you file to cmake

Comment: can you please elaborate i am new to Visual studios

Comment: `make new cmake executable` and link library

Comment: how can I do that please help